# Regex for accepting Aplahanumric and Numeric, but not Alphabates

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, regex

I want the `regular expression` in `java script` which accepts both Alphanumeric and only numeric, space and period is allowed.

**Acceptable:**

Hello Mr. 3367

6576567 55

3432 abc

3333333

ending in...4454

**Not Acceptable**

Hello Mr. Khan

One Two Three

ABCSDS

Comment: Start a request of help with "I want" is not the best option... ;)
Plus, you are not showing us what have you tried... Show us your attempts, please. We can start from them to discuss...

Comment: Add a [mcve] please. =)

Comment: @Andrea Thank you for your guidance. I think I have provided What is required

Comment: @evolutionxbox , Andrea:  I just wanted to know that why downvotes? However, this is a simple question, needs no code or tries. A single line answer was enough to reply, And I can see worthless comments then answers or comments regarding question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this one to fit your needs:

```
/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z ])([a-zA-Z 0-9 ]+)$/
```

Comment: I'm not sure this works... https://regex101.com/r/ZrsUKU/3

Comment: @evolutionxbox it does but you have pasted the entire string with correct and wrong values. it works on an individual line by line basis

Comment: I've included the multi line flag (see the new link), and it still doesn't match anything. Even when pasting line by line, it doesn't match.

Comment: with space and dots, it doesnot work

Comment: you are correct. fixing it

Comment: ^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9 .]+)$ i need this.

Answer (score 1):

You can just check if the string contains numbers using this: `/\d+/`.

**EXAMPLE:**

```js
var strs = ["Hello Mr. 3367",
  "6576567 55",
  "3432 abc",
  "3333333",
  "ending in...4454",
  "Hello Mr. Khan",
  "One Two Three",
  "ABCSDS"
];

strs.forEach(function(s){
  console.log(s + " : " + /\d+/.test(s));
});
```